# Applescript to attach files and then send email to a recipient works if the script is on DT or in Doc folder, but not if placed in Dropbox folder

Tags: applescript, osx-mavericks, email-attachments

I am running Apple OS X  10.11.1 on a Macbook Pro. I use OpenOffice Calc ver 4.1.2 Macros to download SQL data from the internet, do calculations on the data, then create pdf files of the results, which are sent out to folks. The Emailing routines built into OpenOffice Basic work fine on a PC running Windows 7, but on the Mac, The Recipient and Subject fields are not passed to the Mac Mail.app. To solve the problem, I test to see if the file path is PC centric or Mac Centric, and if Mac Centric, I create a text file that has the Mac Centric paths to all the pdf files, then call an Applescript that reads the text file data, adds a subject line and recipient EM address, attaches the pdf files to the email message,  then send the email to the recipient, without any intervention from the user. If the script is on the Desktop or in the Documents folder, it works fine, but not if it is placed in my Dropbox folder. I Get the "Network file permission error. (-5000). I tried to fix the File Permissions by going to Dropbox preferences, holding the options key down and clicking the "Fix Permissions" button, but that does not work either.

Can anyone tell me what to do to fix this. I have included the Applescript and text file so you can see what happens.

```
on run
(* tell application "Finder"
open file "somefile.txt" of folder of (file (path to me))
end tell *)
set myPath to (path to me) as text
set MME_path to POSIX path of myPath
set b to MME_path
set text item delimiters to "/"
set d to {}
set c to text items of b
set myhome to item 3 of c
-- display dialog MME_path & "   " & myhome
set myPrefsFile to item 2 of c & "/" & item 3 of c & "/" & item 4 of c & "/" & item 5 of c & "/EM-Eargv.txt"
open for access myPrefsFile
set PrefsContents to read myPrefsFile using delimiter {","}
close access myPrefsFile
set thesubject to item 1 of PrefsContents
set thebody to ""
set theSender to item 2 of PrefsContents
set theAddress to item 3 of PrefsContents
set theAttachment to item 4 of PrefsContents
set theAttachment1 to POSIX file theAttachment
set theAttachment to item 5 of PrefsContents
set theAttachment2 to POSIX file theAttachment
set theAttachment to item 6 of PrefsContents
set theAttachment3 to POSIX file theAttachment
set theAttachment to item 7 of PrefsContents
set theAttachment4 to POSIX file theAttachment

--set userCanceled to false
--try
--  set dialogResult to display dialog ¬
--      "Path to file is " & theAttachment & " POSIX " & theAttachment1 buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} ¬
--      default button "OK" cancel button ¬
--      "Cancel" giving up after 15 ¬
--      default answer (long user name of (system info))
--on error number -128
--  set userCanceled to true
--end try

tell application "Mail"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:thesubject, content:thebody}
    tell newMessage
        set visible to true
        set sender to theSender
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:theSender, address:theAddress}
        tell content
            make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment1} at after the last paragraph
            make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment2} at after the last paragraph
            make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment3} at after the last paragraph
            make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment4} at after the last paragraph
        end tell
    end tell
    delay 3
    send newMessage
end tell
delay 3
(*
tell application "Mail"
    quit
end tell
*)
end run
```

The Text File is called EM-Eargv.txt

```
EM-Docs Files FYI.,”Your Name”,”YourEMaddress”,file:///Users/admin/Documents/Dropbox/EM-Docs/Sends/Doc1.pdf,file:///Users/admin/Documents/Dropbox/EM-Docs/Sends/Doc2.pdf,file:///Users/admin/Documents/Dropbox/EM-Docs/Sends/Doc3.pdf,file:///Users/admin/Documents/Dropbox/EM-Docs/Sends/Doc4.pdf,
```

You will have to update this text file with your own Name and email address plus change the path to whatever your is and place 4 short PDF files, named Doc1.pdf, Doc2.pdf, Doc3.pdf and Doc4.pdf in a folder called "Sends", before this applescript will send the email to you.

I can send you a short OpenOffice Calc document that creates the Text File with the correct path file data for your computer's configuration but I do not see how to attach the Calc.ods file into this request.

I run the entire example I have from a directory called "EM-Docs" That I can create a Zip file to be downloaded, but again, I do not see a way to attach a zip file to this request.

Comment: Is the problem if the script is saved in your Dropbox folder (as you say), or if the text file EM-Eargv.txt is saved in your Dropbox folder, because that makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, it's this code block that's throwing the error:

```
open for access myPrefsFile
set PrefsContents to read myPrefsFile using delimiter {","}
close access myPrefsFile
```

Place some display dialog messages to debug and find the exact code, like so:

```
display dialog "About to read file"
open for access myPrefsFile
set PrefsContents to read myPrefsFile using delimiter {","}
close access myPrefsFile
display dialog "Just finished reading file" & return & (PresContents as string)
```

But here's the thing, if the problem is the open for access conflict with Dropbox, you don't HAVE to open for access a file if all you're doing is reading it. Just removed the open/close access lines, and try that:

```
display dialog "About to read file"
set PrefsContents to read myPrefsFile using delimiter {","}
display dialog "Just finished reading file" & return & (PresContents as string)
```

If, for some reason you do need to open file access, you could always quit Dropbox, do the file work, then launch Dropbox.